# my images (tagged under div s) are unable to sit side by side on the same row

Tags: html, css

My images won't sit side by side & I'm not sure why.

I've set the display to be inline and it still doesn't work.

I think i should mention that i'd like the 4 colourful buttons to be grouped as how they are now, 2 on top and 2 on the bottom, but i'd still like for it to be inline with the logo and the pfp image..

Here's what I have for the css page so far.

and here's how they currently sit

[image]

*the 'vengage' box is the logo, so it should sit like

on 1 row [vengage][home][settings]   [pfp]

and then have      [fyp]  [search]  directly underneath the home & settings buttons

if it's useful, this is along the lines of how i'd like them to sit on the webpage if possible

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 999px;
  height: 1000px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='logo'>
    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100?text=LOGO' width='100'>
  </div>
  <div class='above'>
    <div class='homebutton'>
      <a href='Code draft.html'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class='settingsbutton'>
      <a href='menusettings.html'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='below'>
    <div class='fypbutton'>
      <a href='fyp.html'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class='searchbutton'>
      <a href='search.html'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pfp">
    <a href="Profile Page.html">
      <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221907/discussion-on-question-by-amy-sdj-my-images-tagged-under-div-s-are-unable-to-s).

Answer (score 1):

Remove display: inline from menu class and add `display: flex` again if you want to align all the elements with the logo than just change the position of menu div, make it as a mother div. Hope it solves your problem

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 999px;
  height: 1000px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <div class='logo'>
    <img src='https://i.ibb.co/h9L3Fyq/logo.jpg'  width='100'>
  </div>
  <div class='above'>
    <div class='homebutton'>
      <a href='Code draft.html'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class='settingsbutton'>
      <a href='menusettings.html'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='below'>
    <div class='fypbutton'>
      <a href='fyp.html'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class='searchbutton'>
      <a href='search.html'>
        <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pfp">
    <a href="Profile Page.html">
      <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x100' width='50'>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

Add `display:flex;` to body. also add `vertical-align:top;`to all image
that is

```
body{
  display:flex;
}
img{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
body{
  width: 999px;
  height: 1000px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:flex;
}

img{
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid #111;
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'>
   <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U82Z.png' width ="75px">
  </div>
  <div class = 'menu'>
      <div class = 'above'></div>
      <div class = 'homebutton'>
          <a href = 'Code draft.html'>
              <img src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM11G.png' width = "50px">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class = 'settingsbutton'>
          <a href = 'menusettings.html'>
              <img src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFcP2.png' width = "50px">
          </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class = 'below'>
      <div class = 'fypbutton'>
          <a href = 'fyp.html'>
              <img src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV49R.png' width = "50px">
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class = 'searchbutton'>
          <a href = 'search.html'>
              <img src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6gVZ.png' width = "50px">
          </a>
      </div>
   </div>
  <div class="pfp">
     <a href="Profile Page.html">
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpEQy.png' width = "29px">
     </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it still displays the same thing as what i have in the question currently ;-;

Comment: are you want all image in a row . and 4 color ful having 2 top and 2 bottom?

Comment: sort of? I'd like for the 4 colourful ones to be stacked ontop of each other, but still inline with the logo and the grey image

Comment: can you add expected output image ?

Comment: just added it :))

Comment: they don't sit side by side T^T,,, the everything excet the logo is vertically stacked

Comment: Are you make any difference from this snippet and [your output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAUOA.png)? Are you want gap between the images?

Comment: the snippet is perfect, i'd like my output to look like that, however for some reason my screen shows something different after i copy and paste the code you've given me into my text editor.

Comment: my screen shows what i've screenshotted in colour in my question

Comment: Are you adding padding or margin to image?

Comment: the image i think,,, it's under the img's class?