# How to get images and or divs to sit side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display 6 images in one row, with 1 image followed by 4 stacked on top of each other in rows of 2, followed by 1 more image

so i'm trying to get it to look something like this
[image]

I've copied and pasted some suggested solutions for other users into my code that should work (in the snippet the posted under a previous question it displayed exactly how i wanted it), but when i refresh my webpage it displays something entirely different.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 999px;
  height: 1000px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'>
        <img src= 'logo.jpg' width =75px>
    </div>
    <div class = 'menu'>
        <div class = 'above'></div>
        <div class = 'homebutton'>
            <a href = 'Code draft.html'>
                <img src = 'menuhome.jpg' width = 50px>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class = 'settingsbutton'>
            <a href = 'menusettings.html'>
                <img src = 'menusettings.jpg' width = 50px>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'below'>
        <div class = 'fypbutton'>
            <a href = 'fyp.html'>
                <img src = 'menufyp.jpg' width = 50px>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class = 'searchbutton'>
            <a href = 'search.html'>
                <img src = 'menusearch.jpg' width = 50px>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pfp">
        <a href="Profile Page.html">
            <img src= 'pfp.jpg' width = 29px>
        </a>
    </div>
```

and what it currently displays on my screen

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [my images (tagged under div s) are unable to sit side by side on the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003926/my-images-tagged-under-div-s-are-unable-to-sit-side-by-side-on-the-same-row)

Comment: uh,, that was me who asked that question hahaha,, but the snippets posted were how i wanted it, it just doesn't display that on my screen T^T

Comment: I made an answer to your previous question

Comment: provide me your logo

Comment: So you asked the same question twice ? why ?>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) , thanks to its very simple [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) you can easily manage what you want to do, in addition it will simply your HTML template and your stylesheet

Comment: In this situation, it could be easily solved with a couple of lines of CSS, and an answer which reflects that will be a lot more helpful than suggesting the use of a library. For next time!